# Is there any way to add element if that not exist in an array.Add element with comma separated?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, include, push

Here in (`data.class_coachee_name`) I am getting list of similar names and different names also.

I am trying to add unique name in the array with comma separate. But push method not adding in array with comma separate:

```
var arrCoachee = [];

for (var x = 0; x < data.class_coachee_name.length; x++) {

var coacheeoutput = data.class_coachee_name[x].coachee_id__coachee_name ;

   if(!arrCoachee.includes(coacheeoutput)){
         arrCoachee.push(coacheeoutput);
      }
}
```

Comment: Can you show what the data type is like in `data` variable?

Comment: can you add your input raw data, so it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

An array is a list of elements, so comma-separated elements doesn't make sense.

You can use [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method to generate a string that includes all elements separated with commas.

Like this:

```js
const myUniqueArray = ['Jim', 'Craig', 'Elon', 'David'];

console.log(myUniqueArray.join()); // comma-separated
console.log(myUniqueArray.join(', ')); // separated with custom delimiter
```